# Sending Email through Outlook not working on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, outlook

While running in debug my code runs fine and emails appropriately through Outlook however when I throw it on IIS (same machine and dev) the emails aren't going through. Any ideas why?

**Current code**

```
try
            {
                //creates outlook app
                Outlook.Application oApp;

                //checks to see if outlook is already running, if not create a new instance of it
                try { 
                    oApp = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"); 
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                }


                // Create a new mail item.
                Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                // Set HTMLBody. 
                //add the body of the email
                oMsg.HTMLBody = "This is an email to notify you that there is a new Experimental MEO added";

                //Subject line
                oMsg.Subject = "NEW MEO EXPERIMENTAL ADDED.";

                // Add a recipient.
                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
                // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("email@address.com");
                oRecip.Resolve();

                // Send.
                ((Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Send();


                // Clean up.
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oMsg);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRecip);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRecips);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp);
            }//end of try block
    catch (Exception ex)
       {
       }//end of catch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Office app (including Outlook) can run in a service (such as IIS).
Your options are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only), [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (which wraps Extended MAPI and can be accessed from any language, including C# - I am its author), EWS (Exchange only) or straight SMTP.